# String Not Equal to Something Else

Tags: string, equals

I am working on android eclipse. This seems an easy question but I haven't found an answer of it yet! I have a string and I want to include in my if statement if that is not equal with something else. But only I know is the mystring.equals("example"). How do I enter if that string is not equal to something else? Thanks a lot

Comment: `if (!mystring.equals("example"))` ?

Comment: omg I am retarded. thanks. I was seaching for something like mystring.notequals

Comment: no problem... if I may suggest.. `thinking in java would` give you a good first insight of the java language programming

Answer (score 4):

> How do I enter if that string is not equal to something else?

Try this guy `!`. Example

```
if (!"someString".equals(myString)){
```

This tells it that if the value of `myString` isn't `someString` then it will enter the `if` condition. Doing it this way instead of

```
if (!myString.equals("someString"){
```

will protect against `NPE` so if `myString` is `null` you won't get an exception in the first example.

Answer (score 0):

To be more precise, the String.equals() function is a function of return type `boolean`.

This means that it either returns `true` or `false` based on the values of the compared strings.

So:

`if(myString.equals("other string"))`

is equivalent to:
`if(myString.equals("other string") == true)`

To test for the contrary, you want:

`if(myString.equals("other string") == false)`

or the equivalent, as codeMagic mentionned:   `if(!myString.equals("other string"))`